# TabPanel: find panel index of a specific component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I have a tab panel containing several panels, each of them contains specific objects.

Given an object id I'd like to find the index of the panel actually containing it...is that possible?

Comment: By object you mean component, or something else?

Comment: Hi, I mean a component

Answer (score 0):

A function like this can do the job:

```
function(tabpanel, selector) {
    var i = 0,
        tabs = tabpanel.items.items,
        len = tabs.length,
        containingTab, currentTab;

    for (len; i<len; i++) {
        currentTab = tabs[i];
        if (currentTab.down(selector)) {
            containingTab = currentTab;
            break;
        }
    }
    return containingTab;
}
```